# Can I transfer saves between devices?

Tags: deus-ex-the-fall

I have multiple Android devices each capable of playing Deus Ex: The Fall, and want to know if it is possible to transfer the saves between devices?

The devices in question are a HTC One phone and a Nexus 7 (2013 edition) - neither of these devices are rooted. I have started playing the game on my phone and will want to continue playing the game later on my tablet.

Since I don't want to be tied down to just one device (my phone is with me all the time whereas my tablet has a larger screen and would probably be more suitable to play the game on) is it possible to continue the same save across both devices, and if so how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I emailed Square Enix mobile support and this is what they said:

> You need to download the app again after changing devices. Save data is also stored in the app itself and will be lost in the process, so you will have to restart the game from the beginning.

So it looks like there isn't an official way to transfer the data.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to root your device, you can probably get success using a backup utility such as TitaniumBackup. That will at least let you transfer the saved data from one device to another, though it won't offer any synchronization other than manual.

Note: the Nexus 7 needs to be wiped to be rooted (you have to unlock the bootloader which causes a factory reset) so root it right after you get it (or at least unlock the bootloader) so that you can back it up later. When you're done with your time machine I could use it for a few things.

Answer (score -2):

Look in the folder android/data/com.squareenix.dxm/ for two folders files and cache in files you have your savegame

Comment: Your answer is hard to read. Can you clean it up a bit?